# Element could not be scrolled into view python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The URL I wanna scrape : https://www.equidia.fr/courses/2023-08-23/R6/C7

To explain, this is a website which is displaying all the horse races in France, and I can scrape all the data in the table this is not the problem, but I'm tryna grab some information that are only displayed when you click on a horse

I don't know how to make that run, I always have the error code "Element could not be scrolled into view", I already tried element.is_displayed, it doesn't works, I already tried execute_script scroll into view and it doesn't too, I tried visibility of content located, and finally I tried all of them in one, but it doesn't work too...

I really don't know how to click on each horse...

Comment: first, find_elements with all horses, second, loop all horses and click it, last, get the detail